# Admin Controller Rewrite Issue

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I have problem in rewriting the admin Customer controller class. It is working fine in my local system but in my server it is not. The following is the code used to rewrite the admin customer controller class:

```
<rewrite>
    <Ritwik_Wishlistenhanced_Customer_exportCsvwishlist>
         <from><![CDATA[#^/admin/customer/exportCsvwishlist#]]></from>
         <to>/wishlistenhanced/customer/exportCsvwishlist</to>
    </Ritwik_Wishlistenhanced_Customer_exportCsvwishlist>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: what is it doing different on your server?  you don't have any permission issues w/ the files do you?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's because production server is running Linux/UNIX which has case-sensitive file system and that influences controllers lookup. So you probably need to change `exportCsvwishlist` to `exportcsvwishlist` in your rewrite and case of yourcontroller.php file

Comment: yes i have remove the case sensitive characters and replaced with below code but also it did not work

  <rewrite>
    <ritwik_wishlistenhanced_customer>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/vcp/customer/#]]></from>
            <to>/wishlistenhanced/customer/</to>
        </ritwik_wishlistenhanced_customer>
  
    </rewrite>

Comment: You have to rename actual controller file as well